# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with ArrayList and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, out-of-memory, android-recyclerview

and thanks in advance for your help.
I'm trying to put an ArrayList into a RecyclerView, but I'm getting back this error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 7224906 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
>               at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
>               at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
>               at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
>               at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
>               at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
>               at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
>               at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
>               at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
>               at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
>               at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
>               at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
>               at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
>               at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:335)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
>               at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>               at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)

My code (the part with the problem) is this:

```
public class TabFragment5 extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_pat_list, container, false);
    setupRecyclerView(rv);
    return rv;
}

private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
            getList(Infos.sPatGrandi)));
}


private ArrayList<String> getList(String[] array) {
    ArrayList<String>list = new ArrayList<String>getList(Infos.sPatGrandi));
    while (list.size()<40){
        list.addAll(getList(Infos.sPatGrandi));
    }
    return list;
}
```

I get this error only with this part of code, can anyone explain me the reason?
Thanks a lot, and have a good time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a recursive call in the method `getList`, allocating so many objects because of this recursive call. This is producing your `OutOfMemoryException`.

**Edit example**:

```
List<String> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();
SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new SimpleStringRecyclerView(context, listOfData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//Now add more content to the list
listOfData.add("new item");
listOfData.add("another item");
//This notifies the adapter and the list that the content has changed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just trying to put my array (Infos.sPatGrandi) into the recyclerview, how can I do it and get rid of the recursive call?

Comment: Add the data to your adapter and call ```notifyDatasetAdapter``` on this adapter.

Comment: Thanks Droidpl for your patience, as you probably have noticed I'm an absolute beginner with coding. My array doesn't change when the app is running, so I don't know if the method you suggested is the best way or maybe there's a simplest way. Could you please write me an example? I can send you my java files if you need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, there is no problem. It is not a matter of a simplest way, it is THE way to proceed. You have to tell your adapter that the content has been modified so the list can refresh its information.

Comment: Example added. This is how the adapters works. You add content to your list, that the adapter has the reference to, and when the data in the list has changed you have to notify the adapter for this change. This will refresh automatically the list in the UI for you.